# Middleman - how do I access Locale / Localization / lang variable

Tags: middleman

Hi wanted to know within templates if there is an easy way to access the lang string for the current translation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access it with `I18n.locale`.

So within ERB ...

`<%= I18n.locale %>`

... and within HAML:

`= I18n.locale`